# Summarize db table player stats on output (multiple entries)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to output a "scoreboard"/"standings" list of hockey players. I currently have a MySQL table like this:

```
statsID | matchID | playerID | goals | assists
120     | 2       | 3        | 4     | 1
121     | 2       | 4        | 2     | 2
122     | 3       | 3        | 0     | 3
```

So for each match the players gets added along with goals and assists. This means that there's multiple entries (several matches) for each player.

So basically, is there a good way to fetch the player data, summarize goals and assists (+ overall points) and output it in a list?

Right now, I have a basic query just outputting each row (as far as my current knowledge reaches). So how can I just output one entry of each player with his stats summarized?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
SELECT t.playerID
     , SUM(t.goals)    AS total_goals
     , SUM(t.assists)  AS total_assists
  FROM sometable t
 GROUP BY t.playerID
 ORDER BY t.playerID
```

Not clear what calculation you use for "overall points", if you are just adding goals and assists, then you can use this in the SELECT list:

```
     , SUM(t.goals)+SUM(t.assists)  AS overall_points
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a group by clause.

```
SELECT playerID, SUM(goals + assist) overall points
FROM   table_name
GROUP BY playerID
```